# no logging for PerformanceMonitorInterceptor

Tags: spring-boot, aop

I've got this simple bean for `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class PerfMetricsConfiguration {
    /**
     * Monitoring pointcut.
     */
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.lapots.breed.judge.repository.*Repository.*(..))")
    public void monitor() {
    }

    /**
     * Creates instance of performance monitor interceptor.
     * @return performance monitor interceptor
     */
    @Bean
    public PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor() {
        return new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(true);
    }

    /**
     * Creates instance of performance monitor advisor.
     * @return performance monitor advisor
     */
    @Bean
    public Advisor performanceMonitorAdvisor() {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("com.lapots.breed.judge.repository.PerfMetricsConfiguration.monitor()");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, performanceMonitorInterceptor());
    }
}
```

It supposed to trace any method invocation in the interfaces that ends with `Repository` in name.
I set logging level in `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor=TRACE
```

But during execution it doesn't write anything in the console. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you happen to be a colleague of the guy asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49072611/1082681)?. Never having seen any question of that kind ever before and now two within a few days is unlikely to be pure chance.

Comment: @kriegaex no I don't know him, but I recall asking similar question some time ago as aspects rarely works from the very beginning in my code lol

Comment: Your point cut will obviously not mach. `setExpression` takes an expression not a reference to a `@Pointcut` annotated method.

Comment: I took the code from here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging

Comment: And did it ever work before you started changing the original?

Comment: @kriegaex I did not test and assumed it should work. I didn't really change anything except pointcut definition

Comment: @kriegaex I see. I thought there might be some evident issue

Comment: No, there is no evident issue. The original code from that other repo works for me. I quickly tried a while ago while waiting for my dinner delivery to arrive.

Comment: Question: Are your `*Repository` interfaces and/or the classes implementing them annotated with `@Component` and picked up as such by Spring? See, this is the problem when (a) you do not develop and debug step by step and (b) do not provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You know, the problem could just be in the code you do **not** show.

Answer (score 15):

I was facing similar issue, after changing the `useDynamicLogger` to false the issue was fixed.

```
@Bean
public PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor() {
  return new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(false);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Faced with the same issue. And as **Manzoor** [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155932/3581539) passing `false` to `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` solves the problem.

Why? When you call `new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(true)`, the logger name used inside of `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` will be: `com.lapots.breed.judge.repository.SomeClass`.

So in your particular case the following logging configuration is required:
`logging.level.com.lapots.breed.judge.repository=TRACE`, otherwise you do not see any logs, the breakpoint on `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace()` will not work and you spend lot's of time thinking you have wrong AOP configuration (while actually it's fine), but you did not set up logging level for proper class/package.

Answer (score 4):

I am using spring logging (SLF4J logging). Instead of putting PerformanceMonitorInterceptor logger to TRACE , I added com.lapots.breed.judge.repository logger to TRACE.
This started printing logs for me.

I did this because the below method in **AbstractTraceInterceptor** is looking for TRACE enabled on the class(Repository) we executing but not on PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.

```
protected boolean isLogEnabled(Log logger) {
        return logger.isTraceEnabled();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this, I simply added this to application.properties and it works:

`logging.level.org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor=trace`

Comment: If this doesn't work, then probably you have some other logging config which is overriding this one.