# PerformanceMonitorInterceptor : Logging time in ns

Tags: spring, performance, monitoring, aspect, pointcut

I'm using Aspects Pointcut to trace the execution time of my SQL call.

Similar to - [no logging for PerformanceMonitorInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106884/no-logging-for-performancemonitorinterceptor).

I'm able to see the trace logs with the respective response time. I see the logged time is in ns unit. Is that the default unit or is there a way we can enforce to print the response time in ms?

Plz assist!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article in order to learn how to best ask questions here. Then edit your question. Many volunteers are here to help you, but you need to help them understand your problem first. Thank you.

Comment: please follow above comment and update question with your attempt and share code snippet and how you tried to have time in ms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.